# вопрос по Hibernate кэш 1 уровня

Tags: java, hibernate

Если объект был обновлен вне Hibernate, то прочитав ранее записанные(в эту сессию) данные мы получим устаревшие значения из 1 уровня кэша ?

Comment: конечно, потому что у hibernate нет никакой информации о состоянии объекта, чтобы сделать invalidate в кэше.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov оффтопик. А зачем нужен кэш 2 уровня? Я так понимаю, он позволяет кэшировать данные на уровне фабрики сессии, тоесть шире чем при сессии. Может еще зачем? Хочется жизненного примера

Comment: вот здесь про кэши http://www.izebit.ru/2015/12/hibernate.html Если коротко, то второй уровень распространяется на все сессии. Например, если у вас есть многопоточное приложение, то врятли вы сделаете, чтобы все потоки работали с одной сессией, и тут помогает кэш второго уровня.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov а почему потокам не хорошо работать с одной сессией? Не могу привести простого примера против этого

Comment: Хорошо, что такое сессия? это объект ассоциированный с какими то данными которые идут в бд. Зафиксировали это. У нас есть потоки, есть обращения к бд. Если каждый поток просто бы сразу скидывал бы изменения в бд было бы ок. Но они могут открывать транзакции. Т.е. данные просто не флушатся в бд, а хранятся в этой сессии, до коммита. Теперь вопрос, как будут себя вести транзакции из разных потоков работающие в одной сессии. Правильно, непонятно как.

Comment: ну я с вами согласен, спасибо. Но с помощью изоляции транзакций, пессимистическая\оптимистическая блокировок можно их заставить работать как надо. Интересно, поддерживает ли это hibernate

Comment: Тут транзакция именно обеспечивается на уровне сессий. Да, хибер поддерживает различные уровни транзакций